# (Flutter-Patrol) How can I run few patrol's tests in the directory to execute one file/test only once?

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test, flutter-patrol

The following hierarchy of the `integration_test` directory:

```
integration_test
├── patrol
   ├── 1_test.dart
   ├── 2_test.dart
   ├── 3_test.dart
   ├── 4_test.dart
   ├── 5_test.dart
   └── 6_test.dart
```

Command to run tests (windows):

`patrol test -t integration_test\patrol\`

Execution of test on the device:

`--------In the loop:`

`first test run  1_test.dart`

`second test run  1_test.dart+ 2_test.dart`

`third test run 1_test.dart+ 2_test.dart+  3_test.dart`

`fourth test run 1_test.dart+ 2_test.dart+  3_test.dart+  4_test.dart`

`... etc... last test run 1_test.dart+ 2_test.dart+  3_test.dart+  4_test.dart+  5_test.dart+  6_test.dart`

-------end of test- test results are displayed correctly

Is it possible, to make the execution simple, single- non-incremental calls, so that calls to a single test are not repeated on the device?

`-In the loop:`

`first test run  1_test.dart`

`second test run 2_test.dart`

`third test run 3_test.dart`

`...`

`last one 6_test.dart`

-------end of test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably missing the `nativeAutomation: true` argument when calling `patrolTest()`.

The author of [this issue](https://github.com/leancodepl/patrol/issues/1657) had the same problem. I recommend reading that thread.

Comment: Thanks for helping, issue is resolved